# How to structure all custom-taxonomy with three verbs(a,b,c) and route them accordingly?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have a website structure in which I have created a custom-taxonomy(topic). Whenever a custom-taxonomy-term is created say "1", its three verbs a,b,c are created and they have their templates of there own.

So to look it in URL form.

custom-taxonomy-term: `example.com/topic/1`

custom-taxonomy-term-verb: `example.com/topic/1/a` , `example.com/topic/1/b` & `example.com/topic/1/c`.

And if someone goes to `example.com/topic/1` they should be automatically redirected to `example.com/topic/1/a`.

I have a diagram attached below for better understanding.

[image: Structure diagram]

How can I get this behaviour in WordPress?

PS: I am not putting all the three in custom-taxonomy templates because of SEO reasons. I want to have an `a`, `b` & `c` for every custom-taxonomy term.

Comment: Why would a b & c being taxonomy terms be a problem for SEO? If there's something that needs to be considered in implementing these you need to say what it is, otherwise any solution isn't going to be meaningfully different to a taxonomy term from an SEO perspective.

Comment: Well, every taxonomy-term has three parts, ask, learn and try. So if there is a custom taxonomy-term "energy", then the user can visit `../energy/ask` to get questions answered. Also, the user can visit `../energy/learn` to learn about things and in try `../energy/try` they can browse product that can be purchased. This wil be for other terms as well. I hope this expalins my use-case.

Comment: So why is this a taxonomy term at all, if most of the content isn't an archive of posts? Couldn't these just be pages with subpages?

Comment: The reason, I went ahead with `custom-taxonomy` is because I wanted to create a solution where the admin would not have to do much of the task. So, once the admin creates a `term` all the other three `verb` should automatically be populated without admin doing anything. These admins would not be very technically sound,t thus I want to make this addition of terms as simple as possible.

Comment: I found this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29604032/how-to-change-page-url-while-you-scroll-down-a-single-page-for-a-wordpress-blog which changes the URL when someone scrolls. And a WordPress website(https://www.webbyawards.com/winners/2013/) is changing URL on the scroll. If this could be possible in tabs. refer to the image (https://imgur.com/a/uL07AKr). Would that be possible with custom-taxonomy terms ??

Comment: How does changing the URL whens someone scrolls have anything to do with your question?

Comment: My ultimate aim is to have `../ask` URL when someone is viewing ASK tab `.../learn` URL when someone is viewing LEARN tab. Please refer to the design (imgur.com/a/uL07AKr) for the custom-taxonomy-template.  Now if I somehow am able to make it happen then it does solve my problem. Earlier, I had thought of replicating this design with links to other verbs, which would look like tabs.